# How can I use javascript to add svg from illustrator to the DOM at run-time?

Tags: javascript, svg

I've created this example here...

http://jsfiddle.net/rhvbG/5/

```
var buttons=[
'<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="25px" height="25px" viewBox="0 0 25 25" style="enable-background:new 0 0 25 25;" xml:space="preserve"><path style="fill:[fill];stroke:[stroke];" d="M19.806,11.844c0,4.072-3.301,7.374-7.373,7.374c-4.073,0-7.374-3.302-7.374-7.374c0-7.344,0.03-7.374,7.374-7.374C16.505,4.47,19.806,7.771,19.806,11.844z"/></svg>',
'<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="25px" height="25px" viewBox="0 0 25 25" style="enable-background:new 0 0 25 25;" xml:space="preserve"><path style="fill:[fill];stroke:[stroke];" d="M19.806,11.844c0,4.072-3.301,7.374-7.373,7.374c-4.073,0-7.374-3.302-7.374-7.374c0-7.344,0.03-7.374,7.374-7.374C16.505,4.47,19.806,7.771,19.806,11.844z"/></svg>'   
];

$(document).ready(function(){
    var colorClasses = {};
    colorClasses["fill"] = "#FF0000";
    colorClasses["stroke"] = "#333333";
    addButtons(buttons, colorClasses);
});

function addButtons(buttons, colorClasses){
    for(var i=0, count = buttons.length; i < count; i++)
        $("#test").append(addColorClasses(colorClasses, buttons[i]));
}

function addColorClasses(classes, string){
    for( var c in classes )
        string = string.replace("[" + c + "]", classes[c]);
    return string;
}
```

The goal is to load in an svg "icon family" via JSON and add them to the page at run time.  Because I only need the basics and I need to be conscious of application size, I was hoping to get a bare bones implementation for changing the color of some svg objects at run time.  I am open to a jquery plugin, provided I can somehow automate the import of an illustrator svg object.  (That's going to be important for workflow)

The link above works on my desktop in FF6 and Chrome (latest), but it is not running in IE or my iOS devices and is obviously not going anywhere.  I'm completely new to SVG, can anyone point me in the right direction here?

I'm placing the svg directly on the page and I'm assuming this is not how it's done.  The examples I have found online show the svg being placed in an object tag, but this will not work for me for several reasons...  I need to be able to change the color via some "tokens" I have set up inside the svg tags for color replacement and it's my understanding that I won't be able to access the svg DOM due to cross domain issues (this will be embedded on external pages).  Further, due to another host of reasons, I need to serve the svg data as part of a master JSON object so I can keep the number of requests down.

ADDED AFTER FIRST RESPONSE:

Just wanted to add that specifically I am trying to add an SVG element to the DOM via an svg string.  For now, I can perform the manipulation on the SVG itself in the rendering environment (the editing environment might be another story) and I would like to avoid using a library (though a jQuery plugin might be acceptable if it's lightweight because I'm already using jQuery).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396746/svg-1-1-javascript-reference

Comment: Sorry, wasn't clear about adding the svg.  Inserting the svg into the browser is no problem, it's the rendering across browser (particularly iDevices, which I'm targeting) that is problematic.  It looks like there is spotty support for "inline svg", which is what I want to do (I think).  http://caniuse.com/svg-html , so it looks like a fairly heavy library is needed to manage the workarounds  I'm not sure how Raphael works around this, but I suspect it's got something to do with the canvas tag?    I'll post the solution when I resolve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many tools for the job, but you should consider using [RaphaelJS](http://raphaeljs.com/) by converting the SVG beforehand into the JSON structure that Raphael uses. Check out http://readysetraphael.com/ for doing that. In addition to being able to interact easily with the SVG nodes, you'll gain compatibility with older IE versions that don't support SVG.

Comment: Cool, I'll do that, thanks.  I was concerned about cross browser support and I thought I saw it wasn't widely supported when I was skimming.  After a second look, the coverage looks pretty good. 60k is  bit heavy for what I was hoping for, but it's not bad if there are no alternatives.

Comment: Added a comment to the original post about just needing to insert the svg via a string.  I am happy to perform the manipulations on the string myself to place it on the page.  It's looking like I might use RaphaelJS in the editing environment, but I think it might be overkill for all I need it to do right now.